# Passing IP address to another ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have two playbooks

1. install azure vm
2. install mongo db and tomcat
   I want to integrate both so first one send ip to second playbook and second play book does its job.

```html
AzurePlaybook.yml

-----All the other tasks----

azure_rm_publicipaddress:
      resource_group: Solutioning
      allocation_method: Static
      name: PublicIP
    register: output_ip_address


- name: Include another playbook
  import_playbook: install_MongoDb_and_Tomcat.yml
```

Second Playbook

```html
install_MongoDb_and_Tomcat.yml

---
- name: install Mongo and Tomcat
  hosts:  demo1
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo       # Set become method
  remote_user: azureuser         # Update username for remote server
  
  vars:
    tomcat_ver: 9.0.30                          # Tomcat version to install
    ui_manager_user: manager                    # User who can access the UI manager section only
    ui_manager_pass: Str0ngManagerP@ssw3rd      # UI manager user password
    ui_admin_username: admin                    # User who can access bpth manager and admin UI sections
    ui_admin_pass: Str0ngAdminP@ssw3rd
    # UI admin password
  roles:
    - install_mongodb
    - mongo_post_install
    - install_tomcat
    - tomcat_post_install
```

I have used import playbook and I want to pass the IP address instead of taking it from inventory file currently install_MongoDb_and_Tomcat.yml playboook taking it from hosts: demo1 which is declared in the inventory file

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in group_vars/all.yml which will make it site wide  global variable.  It'll be overwritten during execution.  Then reference the variable in the new playbook and account for the possibility the variable could be the default (fail/exit fast logic).

See Ansible documentation on variable scoping:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes